# TLS based HTTPS in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

In [Node.JS docs here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/https.html#https_class_https_server) for Node.JS 6.11.4 LTS version, I've read the following

> Class: https.Server Added in: v0.3.4 This class is a subclass of
>   `tls.Server` and emits events same as `http.Server`. See `http.Server` for
>   more information.

Does **the documentation** mean that, requiring and using `'https'` to create a server, will create server based on **HTTPS using TLS**?

[UPDATE]:
Can we specify the type of security like TLS1.1 and TLS 1.2 and NOT TLS 1.0 or SSL?

Comment: If you are unsure what TLS modes and cipher the https server you develop provides just test it out using https://testssl.sh or a similar script.

Comment: Can you imagine a HTTPS server that doesn't use TLS?

Comment: @Robert, Appreciate your suggestion and I tried it and its helpfull. Thank you.